# Extract all pagination links to pages with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['www.onthemarket.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/london/']
    def parse(self, response):
        next_page_url = response.css("li > a.arrow::attr(href)").extract_first()

        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

        print(next_page_url)
```

I need a list with all links to next page. How to traverse all pagination links and extract them with scrapy? They all have  class = arrow.

Comment: if page use JavaScript to add pagination then you need `Selenium` to control web browser which will run JavaScript. Or you have to find url used by JavaScript to get data, and then you can read all from this url.

Comment: can't you keep it in standard list ? or normally `yield` every link and run code with option to save in file and you will get all links in file.

Comment: <a href="/for-sale/property/london/?page=2" class="arrow" title="Next page">
response.css should select title Next page, have no idea how to implement it in response.css

Comment: you don't have to seach "Next page" - it is always last item in `extract()`

Comment: or you may try with CSS selector [:last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.extract_first()` you always get first link in pagination which is link to first or second page.

Using `.extract()[-1]` you get last link in pagination which directs to next page.

```
next_page_url = response.css("li > a.arrow::attr(href)").extract()[-1]
```

---

**EDIT:** or you can use CSS selector [:last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) (with `.extract_first()`)

```
next_page_url = response.css("li > a.arrow:last-child::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

---

**EDIT:** or using xpath and `[last()]`

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('(//li/a[@class="arrow"]/@href)[last()]').extract_first()
```

or

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('(//li/a[@class="arrow"])[last()]/@href').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 4):

For finding and having a link ready when using `scrapy` I always recommend using [`LinkExtractor`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html):

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

...
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        le = LinkExtractor(restrict_css=['li > a.arrow'])
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

You can use it with a lot of different filters like regexes, xpath, or even determine in which tag exactly the link is (by default it finds `a` tags)